# How is there a CPU read misses on exclusive caches?

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-cache, memory-hardware, protocols

If the lower level cache contains blocks that are not present in the higher level cache or other caches then it is said to be exclusive.

It is exclusive because it is only there. How can there be cache miss when CPU is looking for it?

See img:

[image]

Comment: Another piece of information was written the same cache block, thus a read miss. Could this be it?

Comment: Exclusive caches and the exclusive-state in MESI (and variants) are not really related

Comment: In the protocol showed, when the CPU need to evict an "exclusive" block because there is a read cache miss, the CPU will first write-back data then load new data and place the cache line in the shared state. This diagram don't show cache fill operations.

Comment: @PawełBatko Is it possible that exclusive blocks be replaced by another piece of information?

Comment: @TEMLIB Could you elaborate on that?